# Select all duplicate rows based on one or two columns?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I Have a table named `contacts` with fields

```
+-----+------------+-----------+
| id  | first_name | last_name |
+-----+------------+-----------+
```

I want to display all duplicates based on `first_name` and (/ or) `last_name`, e.g:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | mukta      | chourishi |
|  2 | mukta      | chourishi |
|  3 | mukta      | john      |
|  4 | carl       | thomas    |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

If searched on just `first_name` it should return:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

But if searched on both `first_name` and `last_name` should return:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to achieve your result is using nested query and having clause: In inner query select those having count more then one, and in outer query select id:

Check following example for single column selection criteria:

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `first` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    `last` varchar(120) NOT NULL
);
```

Insert tuple:

```
INSERT INTO `person` ( `first`, `last`) VALUES
("mukta", "chourishi"),
("mukta", "chourishi"),
("mukta", "john"),
("carl", "thomas" );
```

The result you need:

```
mysql> SELECT  `id` 
    -> FROM `person` 
    -> WHERE `first`=(SELECT `first` FROM `person` HAVING COUNT(`first`) > 1);
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**[ANSWER]**

But as if you selection criteria is on the basis of more than one columns then you can make use of JOIN.

To explain it I am writing a selection query that creates an intermediate table that will be use in JOIN as second operand table.

Query is select all fist name and column those duplicates with some of other rows:
For example select rows in which `first` and `last` name repeats

```
mysql> SELECT `first`, `last`,  count(*)  as rows 
    -> FROM `person` 
    -> GROUP BY `first`, `last` 
    -> HAVING count(rows) > 1;
+-------+-----------+------+
| first | last      | rows |
+-------+-----------+------+
| mukta | chourishi |    2 |
+-------+-----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you have only one pair of `first` and `last` names those repeats (or is duplicates with some other rows).

Now, question is: how to select `id` of this row? Use Join! as follows:

```
mysql> SELECT  p1.`id`
    -> FROM `person` as p1
    -> INNER JOIN (
    ->     SELECT `first`, `last`,  count(*)  as rows
    ->     FROM `person` 
    ->     GROUP BY `first`, `last` 
    ->     HAVING count(rows) > 1) as p
    -> WHERE p.`first` = p1.`first` and p.`last` = p1.`last`;  
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

you can select on the basis of as many columns as you wants e.g. single column if you want using join then remove last name.

Comment: Oh Thanks Grijesh.You just made my day...The query worked perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

and you write sql function which takes two parameters firstname and lastname and inside the functions you write your conditions if lastname=null find duplicates for firstname, and if firstname is null, find duplicates for the lastname, and so on so forth

the statemnets inside the conditions is

```
-- to show the duplicates for firstname
select id from table where first_name='name' 

-- to show duplicates for firstname and last name
select id from table where first_name='name' and last_name='lname' 

-- to show duplicates for firstname or last name
select id from table where first_name='name' or last_name='lname'
```

Comment: I suggest you read question again. OP want all row those are duplicate. I confuses.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i think you need to read it once again :) because he wants to show the IDs of the duplicate rows only look at his expected results

Comment: it displays the IDs of the duplicates

Comment: How do you checks that `'name'`  duplicates in tables?

Comment: the question said if i want to search by first name it will give me all the duplicate ids for the first name which is normal select , and if i want to search by first name and last name it should give me all the ids for the duplicated firstname and last name, again it is normal select. the only way to doit is to create a function that will check the condition if you want to search by firstname or by firstname lastname

Comment: Still not sure how do you checks if name duplicates, Anyways if you wins then I will vote you and beg you for a treat...

Comment: I am not passing any parameters.Just need to display duplicates on specific criteria.