# sql select if they have more than once

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table that share the same ID:

Table Colors:

```
id  color
---------
1   blue
1   red
1   green
1   blue
2   green
2   yellow
2   orange
3   red
3   orange
3   yellow
3   orange
```

Table Names:

```
id   name
---------
1    John
2    Anna
3    Mike
```

What would be the query to find the names where any color occurs more than once.

for example: John and Mike is the answer as John has blue twice and Mike has orange twice too.

many thanks

Comment: Sorry not a duplicate of [Select all duplicate rows based on one or two columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21794704/1673391), just a  related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT A.name, B.color, count(*) 'color count' 
FROM Names A JOIN Colors B on A.id = B.id
GROUP BY A.id, B.color
HAVING Count(*)>1
```

Check it here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee040/3

Comment: John and Mike is the answer as John has blue **twice** and Mike has orange **twice** too

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, color, COUNT(*)
FROM Names
JOIN Colors
  ON Names.id = Colors.id
GROUP BY name, color
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.name FROM Colour c
INNER JOIN Names n ON (n.id = c.id)
GROUP BY n.name, c.colour
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select n.Name
From names n
Join colors c on c.ID = n.ID
Group by n.Name
Having count(c.color) <> count(distinct c.color)
```